# Not getting sorted data with lodash sortBy()

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have array of objects which I want to sort with by name. I am using lodash library and use _.sortBy(). But by using this function I am not getting proper reponse.

Following is my activeUser array

```js
[ { date: 'Tue Dec 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '10:30',
    user_name: 'Happy Teachers DAy',
    profilepic: 'http://192.168.0.109:8000//igXFkPIcNxSlhl0IB6c9iOexn.jpeg',
    activeType: 'Group',
    _id: '5b8f591bfd6e99021a2f1dd1',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: [] },
  { date: 'Tue Dec 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '16:00',
    user_name: 'Practice Group',
    profilepic: null,
    activeType: 'Group',
    _id: '5bc1dce4b9d0faf0271e0ef5',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: [] },
  { date: 'Tue Dec 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '16:00',
    user_name: 'Practice Group',
    profilepic: null,
    activeType: 'Group',
    _id: '5bc1dce4b9d0faf0271e0ef5',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: [] },
  { date: 'Sat Dec 15 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '12:00',
    user_name: 'Jayna',
    profilepic: 'http://192.168.0.110:8000/D5sd646Tlx3zuOvWqhesSjIoL.jpeg',
    activeType: 'Individual',
    _id: '5b289024e019bb7623761bae',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: [] },
  { date: 'Fri Dec 12 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '14:00',
    user_name: 'GCK',
    profilepic: 'http://192.168.0.110:8000/LDS3CpweCSSDDdOfa4lR6rPmn.jpeg',
    activeType: 'Individual',
    _id: '5ae1691241ce6c991f45b7fc',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: [] },
  { date: 'Fri Dec 11 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '16:00',
    user_name: 'kaushik',
    profilepic: 'http://192.168.0.110:8000/DNAtiR1iiG2jgJWsIH5tpZCwv.jpeg',
    activeType: 'Individual',
    _id: '5b502b2724f36ada24167083',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: [] } ]
```

sortedName = _.sortBy(activeUser, ['user_name']);

Code of groupBy is below:

```js
var date = function (d) {
        if (d.fullname != null || d.fullname != undefined) {
          return d.fullname.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
        }
      }
      // map a group to the required form
      var groupToSummary = function (group, date) {
        return {
          date: date,
          data: group
        }
      }
      var data = _(sortedName)
        .groupBy(date)
        .map(groupToSummary)
        .value();
```

In sortedName I am getting following array as response:

```js
[
        {
            "date": "G",
            "data": [
                {
                    "date": "Fri Dec 12 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
                    "time": "14:00",
                    "user_name": "GCK",
                    "profilepic": "http://192.168.0.110:8000/LDS3CpweCSSDDdOfa4lR6rPmn.jpeg",
                    "activeType": "Individual",
                    "_id": "5ae1691241ce6c991f45b7fc",
                    "isCreatedByTherapist": false,
                    "groupMember": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "H",
            "data": [
                {
                    "date": "Mon Dec 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
                    "time": "18:00",
                    "user_name": "Happy Teachers DAy",
                    "profilepic": "http://192.168.0.110:8000//igXFkPIcNxSlhl0IB6c9iOexn.jpeg",
                    "activeType": "Group",
                    "_id": "5b8f591bfd6e99021a2f1dd1",
                    "isCreatedByTherapist": false,
                    "groupMember": [
                        {
                            "groupMemberId": "5b46f08262efab2027ecce7a",
                            "_id": "5b90a8385ef8155c17865afc",
                            "isMultiSession": false
                        },
                        {
                            "groupMemberId": "5b502b2724f36ada24167083",
                            "_id": "5b90a8385ef8155c17865afb",
                            "isMultiSession": false
                        },
                        {
                            "groupMemberId": "5ae1691241ce6c991f45b7fc",
                            "_id": "5b90a8385ef8155c17865af9",
                            "isMultiSession": false
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "date": "Tue Dec 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
                    "time": "10:30",
                    "user_name": "Happy Teachers DAy",
                    "profilepic": "http://192.168.0.110:8000//igXFkPIcNxSlhl0IB6c9iOexn.jpeg",
                    "activeType": "Group",
                    "_id": "5b8f591bfd6e99021a2f1dd1",
                    "isCreatedByTherapist": false,
                    "groupMember": [
                        {
                            "groupMemberId": "5b46f08262efab2027ecce7a",
                            "_id": "5b90a8385ef8155c17865afc",
                            "isMultiSession": false
                        },
                        {
                            "groupMemberId": "5b502b2724f36ada24167083",
                            "_id": "5b90a8385ef8155c17865afb",
                            "isMultiSession": false
                        },
                        {
                            "groupMemberId": "5ae1691241ce6c991f45b7fc",
                            "_id": "5b90a8385ef8155c17865af9",
                            "isMultiSession": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "J",
            "data": [
                {
                    "date": "Sat Dec 15 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
                    "time": "12:00",
                    "user_name": "Jayna",
                    "profilepic": "http://192.168.0.110:8000/D5sd646Tlx3zuOvWqhesSjIoL.jpeg",
                    "activeType": "Individual",
                    "_id": "5b289024e019bb7623761bae",
                    "isCreatedByTherapist": false,
                    "groupMember": []
                },
                {
                    "date": "Sat Dec 10 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
                    "time": "11:00",
                    "user_name": "Jayna",
                    "profilepic": "http://192.168.0.110:8000/D5sd646Tlx3zuOvWqhesSjIoL.jpeg",
                    "activeType": "Individual",
                    "_id": "5b289024e019bb7623761bae",
                    "isCreatedByTherapist": false,
                    "groupMember": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "P",
            "data": [
                {
                    "date": "Tue Dec 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
                    "time": "16:00",
                    "user_name": "Practice Group",
                    "profilepic": null,
                    "activeType": "Group",
                    "_id": "5bc1dce4b9d0faf0271e0ef5",
                    "isCreatedByTherapist": false,
                    "groupMember": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "K",
            "data": [
                {
                    "date": "Fri Dec 11 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
                    "time": "16:00",
                    "user_name": "kaushik",
                    "profilepic": "http://192.168.0.110:8000/DNAtiR1iiG2jgJWsIH5tpZCwv.jpeg",
                    "activeType": "Individual",
                    "_id": "5b502b2724f36ada24167083",
                    "isCreatedByTherapist": false,
                    "groupMember": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

As you can see, the last two objects are not proper!!

Please help me out!!! Anyone's help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: What does activeUser look like ?

Comment: It would seem like your "Active User" array is an array of objects that have a `date` property and a `data` property, so sorting those on `'user_name'` would have no effect.

Comment: @Ankit, I edited my question

Comment: @crashmstr, yes, activeUser is an array of objects.. And that contains date as well as user_name field.. I have to sort this array according to date wise and user_name wise.. 
And yes, I grouped by this array with date field..

Comment: You still skip the code showing how you group by and still show impossible results from the `sortBy`. Please show your *real* code.

Comment: I edited the code which @crashmstr you want to see!!

Comment: So... your question is not about `_.sortBy`, but `_.groupBy`? That is a very different question.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input data you show, I still cannot get the results you are getting, but it seems strange to call the capitalized first letter a "date", plus the fact you have code that references `full_name` but no property of that value in the data.

Lower case `k` comes after all the upper case values using `_.sortBy`, so this might be part of the problem and why the "K" group comes last, but given the code, data, and output you show are not "possible", I'm not sure how else I could help.

```js
var  activeUser  =   [{
    date: 'Tue Dec 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '10:30',
    user_name: 'Happy Teachers DAy',
    profilepic: 'http://192.168.0.109:8000//igXFkPIcNxSlhl0IB6c9iOexn.jpeg',
    activeType: 'Group',
    _id: '5b8f591bfd6e99021a2f1dd1',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: []
  },
  {
    date: 'Tue Dec 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '16:00',
    user_name: 'Practice Group',
    profilepic: null,
    activeType: 'Group',
    _id: '5bc1dce4b9d0faf0271e0ef5',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: []
  },
  {
    date: 'Tue Dec 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '16:00',
    user_name: 'Practice Group',
    profilepic: null,
    activeType: 'Group',
    _id: '5bc1dce4b9d0faf0271e0ef5',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: []
  },
  {
    date: 'Sat Dec 15 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '12:00',
    user_name: 'Jayna',
    profilepic: 'http://192.168.0.110:8000/D5sd646Tlx3zuOvWqhesSjIoL.jpeg',
    activeType: 'Individual',
    _id: '5b289024e019bb7623761bae',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: []
  },
  {
    date: 'Fri Dec 12 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '14:00',
    user_name: 'GCK',
    profilepic: 'http://192.168.0.110:8000/LDS3CpweCSSDDdOfa4lR6rPmn.jpeg',
    activeType: 'Individual',
    _id: '5ae1691241ce6c991f45b7fc',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: []
  },
  {
    date: 'Fri Dec 11 2018 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)',
    time: '16:00',
    user_name: 'kaushik',
    profilepic: 'http://192.168.0.110:8000/DNAtiR1iiG2jgJWsIH5tpZCwv.jpeg',
    activeType: 'Individual',
    _id: '5b502b2724f36ada24167083',
    isCreatedByTherapist: false,
    groupMember: []
  }
]; 
let sortedArray = _
  .chain(activeUser)
  .sortBy(['user_name'])
  .groupBy(function(d) {
    if (d.fullname != null || d.fullname != undefined) {
      return d.fullname.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    } else {
      return d.user_name.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    }
  })
  .map(function(group, date) {
    return ({
      date: date,
      data: group
    });
  })
  .value();

console.dir(sortedArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```